# Sapper/Svelte - How to fetch periodically

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

How would I periodically fetch data using Sapper?

Is this the correct way?

```
//src/routes/fetch_on_this_page.svelte

<script>
  setInterval(async () => {
    //fetch here
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You could of course use setInterval, you would probably want to clear it on component destroy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The neatest way to do this is to do it all inside `onMount`:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  onMount(() => {
    async function fetchData() {...}
    
    const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 3000);
    fetchData();

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });
</script>
```

Aside from creating fewer component-level variables, `onMount` code doesn't run in during server-side rendering, so involves less work. If you needed to do this in multiple components you could also wrap this up into a custom lifecycle function:

```js
// poll.js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

export function poll(fn, ms) {
  onMount(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(fn, ms);
    fn();

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });
}
```

```html
<script>
  import { poll } from './poll.js';

  poll(async function fetchData() {
    // your implementation goes here
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Syntax error: `return () => clearInterval(interval));` should be something like`return () => clearInterval(interval)`, otherwise works very well.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
  import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";

  async function fetchData() {
  //Fetch
  }

  const interval = setInterval(async () => {
    fetchData();
  }, 3000);

  onMount(async () => {
    fetchData();
  });

  onDestroy(() => clearInterval(interval));
</script>
```

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/ondestroy

Comment: This is explained in detail in the [svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/ondestroy).